# Extremely slow import of module skimage.io

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, scikit-learn, scikit-image

Just reinstalled numpy (built against MKL), scipy, cython, pil, scikit-learn and scikit-image in a new virtualenv and I am getting extremely slow import time of the module skimage.io:

```
  import skimage         --> 0.07536911964 secs
  from skimage import io --> 3.15395903587 secs
```

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried timing the import of `matplotlib`? That's one of the plugins used by `skimage.io`.

The `io` subpackage is mostly a wrapper around these other libraries (and includes wrappers for `PIL`, `tifffile`, `imread`, `freeimage`, etc). At import, the package looks for a default backend (usually `matplotlib` and `PIL`, on most systems). One of these dependencies is most likely responsible for the slow import.